# bash: python: command not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, python-2.7, sublimetext3

I've recently installed Sublime text on Ubuntu. When I try to run some python code, the following error is popped up:

```
bash: python: command not found
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/home/user/Desktop/Python Project/test.py"]
[dir: /home/user/Desktop/Python Project]
[path: /home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]
```

when I run
`python` on the commandline, I get:

```
  command 'python3' from deb python3
  command 'python' from deb python-is-python3
```

When I run
`python3`
on the commandline, I get:

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: Is python itself installed on your computer?

Comment: If you go to the command line, what does `which python3` return?

Comment: These are build notes, not an error. Please include the error itself.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, I've installed python on my computer.

Comment: @MattDMo it returns ```/usr/bin/python3```

Comment: @MusabGuma'a This is what shows up on the terminal after running python code. Nothing else.

Comment: What command do you usually use for running python?  Is it `python` or `python3`?

Comment: @JohnGordon I use ```python```

Comment: What is `python` -- is it an alias or an actual binary?

Comment: @JohnGordon when I run ```python``` on the commandline, I get:
```Command 'python' not found, did you mean:

  command 'python3' from deb python3
  command 'python' from deb python-is-python3``` 
When I run ```python3``` on the commandline, I get:
```Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.```

Comment: Is there a way you can configure Sublime Text to use `python3` as the command instead of `python`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sublime Text is configuring python instead of python3.
You just need to add a new build system to the Sublime Text.
To do that, Select `Tools` > `Build System` > `New Build System...`
Now, a new file will open. Add the following code to this file:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Now, save the file as `Python3.sublime-build`.
Now, change you `Build System` to `Python3` and try to run you code again. Now, it should run successfully.